# How can I get the length of a two dimensional array in VBA (excel)?

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

How can I get the length of a two-dimensional array in VBA (excel)?

Dim givenData(5, 7) As Double

I need a command that would return 5,
And a command that would return 7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644231/vba-using-ubound-on-a-multidimensional-array, http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/size-of-an-array.html

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264295.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub ShowArrayBounds()
    Dim givenData(3 To 5, 5 To 7) As Double

    MsgBox LBound(givenData, 1)
    MsgBox UBound(givenData, 1)
    MsgBox LBound(givenData, 2)
    MsgBox UBound(givenData, 2)

End Sub
```

You can use `UBound-LBound + 1` to get the "size" for each dimension