# How to get Array Dimension(array parameter pass error)?

Tags: arrays, vb6

I'm trying to get the dimension of an array via `PeekArray` and `SafeArrayGetDim` API,
But the "Type mismatch" when compiling.
And if `Debug.Print SafeArrayGetDim(PeekArray(TestArray).Ptr)` will work fine.

Please find below the VB code.
Any help will be greatful.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type PeekArrayType
    Ptr As Long
    Reserved As Currency
End Type

Private Declare Function PeekArray Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
    Arr() As Any, Optional ByVal Length As Long = 4) As PeekArrayType

Private Declare Function SafeArrayGetDim Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByVal Ptr As Long) As Long


Sub GetArrayDimension()
    Dim TestArray() As Long
    ReDim TestArray(3, 2)
    Debug.Print fnSafeArrayGetDim(TestArray)
End Sub


Function fnSafeArrayGetDim(varRunArray As Variant) As Long
    Dim varTmpArray() As Variant
    varTmpArray = varRunArray
    fnSafeArrayGetDim = SafeArrayGetDim(PeekArray(varTmpArray).Ptr)
End Function
```

Comment: `RtlMoveMemory` [has](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/rtlmovememory) three parameters and does not return anything. If you want an array pointer to pass to SafeArray functions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/183668/11683.

Comment: @GSerg, Thanks, I may spend some time to study it.

Comment: Is this code based on [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?736285-VB6-Returning-Detecting-Empty-Arrays&p=4538659&viewfull=1#post4538659) post? What should `fnSafeArrayGetDim` return for `ReDim TestArray(5, 6)` - 2, 5 or 6?

Comment: @wqw, it should return 2

Comment: @EricHu Did you see the linked post? There is already a `PeekSafeArray(PeekArray(aTemp).Ptr).cDims` which does that with no call to `SafeArrayGetDim`.

Comment: @wqw sorry, I didn't get what you mean, which link? and it's on VB6?

Comment: @EricHu The link is in my comment above. Search for "Is this code based on this post" if you can't immediately find it.

Comment: @wqw, thanks for your advising, I just replace "SafeArrayGetDim" by PeekSafeArray, and try to pack PeekSafeArray(PeekArray(varTmpArray).Ptr).cDims as universal function, but it's still "type mismatch" error!

Comment: It's complicated. I just posted a complete working answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working `fnSafeArrayGetDim` function

```
Option Explicit

#Const HasPtrSafe = (VBA7 <> 0) Or (TWINBASIC <> 0)

#If Win64 Then
    Private Const PTR_SIZE                  As Long = 8
#Else
    Private Const PTR_SIZE                  As Long = 4
#End If

#If HasPtrSafe Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#Else
    Private Enum LongPtr
        [_]
    End Enum
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#End If

Public Function fnSafeArrayGetDim(varRunArray As Variant) As Long
    Const VT_BYREF      As Long = &H4000
    Dim lVarType        As Long
    Dim lPtr            As LongPtr
    
    Call CopyMemory(lVarType, varRunArray, 2)
    If (lVarType And vbArray) <> 0 Then
        Call CopyMemory(lPtr, ByVal VarPtr(varRunArray) + 8, PTR_SIZE)
        If (lVarType And VT_BYREF) <> 0 Then
            Call CopyMemory(lPtr, ByVal lPtr, PTR_SIZE)
        End If
        If lPtr <> 0 Then
            Call CopyMemory(fnSafeArrayGetDim, ByVal lPtr, 2)
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim TestArray() As Long
    ReDim TestArray(3, 2)
    Debug.Print fnSafeArrayGetDim(TestArray)
End Sub
```

You don't need `PeekArray` as you are dealing with pure `Variant`s not arrays like `Variant()` (array of `Variant`s), `Long()` (array of `Long`s) or `Byte()` (array of `Byte`s) generally a type ending with `()` in VB6 is so called `SAFEARRAY` in COM parlance.

So your `varRunArray` is a pure `Variant` that points to a `SAFEARRAY` in its `pparray` member which is located at `VarPtr(varRunArray) + 8`. Once you get this pointer you must heed the `VT_BYREF` flag in `Variant`'s `vt` which introduces a double indirection (you have to dereference `lPtr = *lPtr` once more). At this point if you get a non-NULL pointer to the `SAFEARRAY` structure then the `cDim` member is in the first 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Here 's my solution, the **ArrayDims** function, adapted from wqw's post, above.  In addition to wqw's basic logic, this solution will compile under VBA7/64-bit Office environments; it includes improved self-documentation and explanatory commentary; it eliminates the embedded constants and, instead, uses standard VB/VBA Type structures and Enum values where useful, and provides all associated Type elements and Enum values for reference.  You can, of course, pare this down to the minimum necessary declarations and Enum values.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
        Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
        Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If

Enum VariantTypes
    VTx_Empty = vbEmpty         '(0) Uninitialized
    VTx_Null = vbNull           '(1) No valid data
    VTx_Integer = vbInteger     '(2)
    VTx_Long = vbLong           '(3)
    VTx_FloatSingle = vbSingle  '(4) Single-precision floating-point
    VTx_FloatDouble = vbDouble  '(5) Double-precision floating-point
    VTx_Currency = vbCurrency   '(6)
    VTx_DATE = vbDate           '(7)
    VTx_String = vbString       '(8)
    VTx_Object = vbObject       '(9)
    VTx_Error = vbError         '(10) An Error condition code
    VTx_Boolean = vbBoolean     '(11)
    VTx_Variant = vbVariant     '(12) Used only for arrays of Variants
    VTx_Byte = vbByte           '(17)
    VTx_UDT = vbUserDefinedType '(36) User-defined data types
    VTx_Array = vbArray         '(8192)
    VTx_ByRef = &H4000          '(16384) Is an indirect pointer to the Variant's data
End Enum

Type VariantStruct  'NOTE - the added "X_..." prefixes force the VBE Locals window to display the elements in
                    'their correct adjacency order:
    A_VariantType      As Integer  '(2 bytes) See the VariantTypes Enum, above.
    B_Reserved(1 To 6) As Byte     '(6 bytes)
    C_Data             As LongLong '(8 bytes) NOTE: for an array-Variant, its Data is a pointer to the array.
End Type

Type ArrayStruct    'NOTE - the added "X_..." prefixes force the VBE Locals window to display the elements in
                    'their correct adjacency order:
                 
    A_DimCount      As Integer  '(aka cDim) 2 bytes: The number of dimensions in the array.
    B_FeatureFlags  As Integer  '(aka fFeature) 2 bytes: See the FeatureFlags Enum, below.
    C_ElementSize   As Long     '(aka cbElements) 4 bytes: The size of each element in the array.
    D_LockCount     As Long     '(aka cLocks) 4 bytes: The count of active locks on the array.
    E_DataPtr       As Long     '(aka pvData) 4 bytes: A pointer to the first data element in the array.
    F_BoundsInfoArr As LongLong '(aka rgsabound) 8 bytes, min.: An info-array of SA_BoundInfo elements (see below)
                                ' that contains bounds data for each dimension of the safe-array.  There is one
                                ' SA_BoundInfo element for each dimension in the array.  F_BoundsInfoArr(0) holds
                                ' the information for the right-most dimension and F_BoundsInfoArr[A_DimCount - 1]
                                ' holds the information for the left-most dimension.  Each SA_BoundInfo element is
                                ' 8 bytes, structured as follows:
End Type

Private Type SA_BoundInfo
    ElementCount As Long        '(aka cElements) 4 bytes: The number of elements in the dimension.
    LBoundVal As Long           '(aka lLbound) 4 bytes: The lower bound of the dimension.
End Type

Enum FeatureFlags
    FADF_AUTO = &H1         'Array is allocated on the stack.
    FADF_STATIC = &H2       'Array is statically allocated.
    FADF_EMBEDDED = &H4     'Array is embedded in a structure.
    FADF_FIXEDSIZE = &H10   'Array may not be resized or reallocated.
    FADF_BSTR = &H100       'An array of BSTRs.
    FADF_UNKNOWN = &H200    'An array of IUnknown pointers.
    FADF_DISPATCH = &H400   'An array of IDispatch pointers.
    FADF_VARIANT = &H800    'An array of VARIANT type elements.
    FADF_RESERVED = &HF0E8  'Bits reserved for future use.
End Enum

Function ArrayDims(SomeArray As Variant) As Long 'Cast the array argument to an array-Variant (if it isn't already)
                                                 'for a uniform reference-interface to it.
    '
    'Returns the number of dimensions of the specified array.
    '
    'AUTHOR: Peter Straton
    '
    'CREDIT: Adapted from wqw's post, above.
    '
    '*************************************************************************************************************
    
    Dim DataPtrOffset   As Integer
    Dim DimCount        As Integer  '= ArrayStruct.A_DimCount (2 bytes)
    Dim VariantType     As Integer  '= VariantStruct.A_VariantType (2 bytes)
    Dim VariantDataPtr  As LongLong '= VariantStruct.C_Data (8 bytes). See note about array-Variants' data, above.
    
    'Check the Variant's type
    
    Call CopyMemory(VariantType, SomeArray, LenB(VariantType))
    If (VariantType And VTx_Array) Then
        'It is an array-type Variant, so get its array data-pointer
        
        Dim VariantX As VariantStruct   'Unfortunately, in VB/VBA, you can't reference the size of a user-defined
                                        'data-Type element without instantiating one.
        DataPtrOffset = LenB(VariantX) - LenB(VariantX.C_Data) 'Takes advantage of C_Data being the last element
        Call CopyMemory(VariantDataPtr, ByVal VarPtr(SomeArray) + DataPtrOffset, LenB(VariantDataPtr))
        
        If VariantDataPtr <> 0 Then
            If (VariantType And VTx_ByRef) Then
                'The passed array argument was not an array-Variant, so this function-call's cast to Variant type
                'creates an indirect reference to the original array, via the Variant parameter.  So de-reference
                'that pointer.
                
                Call CopyMemory(VariantDataPtr, ByVal VariantDataPtr, LenB(VariantDataPtr))
            End If
            
            If VariantDataPtr <> 0 Then
                'Now have a legit Array reference, so get and return its dimension-count value
                
                Call CopyMemory(DimCount, ByVal VariantDataPtr, LenB(DimCount))
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    ArrayDims = DimCount
End Function 'ArrayDims

Sub Demo_ArrayDims()
    '
    'Demonstrates the functionality of the ArrayDims function using a 1-D, 2-D and 3-D array of various types
    '
    '*************************************************************************************************************
    
    Dim Test2DArray As Variant
    Dim Test3DArray() As Long

    Debug.Print 'Blank line
    Debug.Print ArrayDims(Array(20, 30, 400)) 'Test 1D array
    
    Test2DArray = [{0, 0, 0, 0; "Apple", "Fig", "Orange", "Pear"}]
    Debug.Print ArrayDims(Test2DArray)
    
    ReDim Test3DArray(1 To 3, 0 To 1, 1 To 4)
    Debug.Print ArrayDims(Test3DArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, fixed my submission to work on x64 version of VBA too.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
Function fnSafeArrayGetDim(ByRef varRunArray() As Long) As Long
    Dim varTmpArray() As Long
    varTmpArray = varRunArray
    fnSafeArrayGetDim = SafeArrayGetDim(PeekArray(varTmpArray).Ptr)
End Function
```

You cannot put a `Dim TestArray() As Long` in a `Dim varTmpArray() As Variant` what you try here `varTmpArray = varRunArray`.

If you want to be more generic then use

```
Function fnSafeArrayGetDim(ByRef varRunArray As Variant) As Long
    Dim varTmpArray As Variant
    varTmpArray = varRunArray
    fnSafeArrayGetDim = SafeArrayGetDim(PeekArray(varTmpArray).Ptr)
End Function
```

For example:

You cannot put a `Long` array into a `Variant` **array**

```
Sub ThisDoesNotWork()
    Dim TestArray() As Long
    ReDim TestArray(3, 2)
    
    Dim varTmpArray() As Variant 'with parenthesis
    varTmpArray = TestArray
End Sub
```

but you can put a `Long` array into a `Variant` (that is not an array)

```
Sub ThisWorks()
    Dim TestArray() As Long
    ReDim TestArray(3, 2)
    
    Dim varTmpArray As Variant 'note this is without parenthesis!
    varTmpArray = TestArray
End Sub
```

and you can put a `Long` array into another `Long` array

```
Sub ThisWorksToo()
    Dim TestArray() As Long
    ReDim TestArray(3, 2)
    
    Dim varTmpArray() As Long 'with parenthesis it has to be the same type as TestArray
    varTmpArray = TestArray
End Sub
```

Comment: Peh, yes, I knew the issue, but what if I would like to make the "fnSafeArrayGetDim" function as universal function, and I can't sure which kind of array will be pass to "fnSafeArrayGetDim" function

Comment: @EricHu Well, see my examples there is a difference between declaring `Dim varTmpArray As Variant` and `Dim varTmpArray() As Variant` you want to go with the first one without the parenthesis then. • But also have a look at GSerg's comment as your function declarations seem to be wrong too.

Comment: Peh, the "ThisWorks()" could work, but once pass the "varTmpArray" as parameter to PeekArray API, the "Type Mismatch" error may encounter again.

Comment: @EricHu have a look at what GSerg posted or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35275722) your function declaration is wrong!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ His API declaration for `RtlMoveMemory` is not wrong although a bit unusual. It works because in stdcall "large" UDTs as retval are passed on the stack **before** the first actual argument, so in his case the stack layout for the retval coincide with the original declare's `Destination` parameter and only two more actual arguments need to be pushed/declared in addition. Weird but it works, I checked the disassembly when stumbled upon this several years ago.