# excel vba Ubound/Lbound error

Tags: vba, excel

UBound seems to not be returning anything. I am using the Pricer function in excel and passing it a column. Did I mismatch my data types? I UBound on a dummy array that accessed arrP.Value and that didnt work either. Thoughts?

```
Function Pricer(arrP As Variant) As Double
        sd = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDevP(arrP)
        avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(arrP)
        PriceUB = avg + sd
        PriceLB = avg - sd
        MsgBox UBound(aarP)
        Pricer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(arrP)
End Function
```

Comment: `Range.Value` is 2 dimensional.

Comment: Slice with Index into one dimensional array and pass/

Comment: in `MsgBox UBound(aarP)` the `aarP` should be `arrP`. Otherwise, it should work fine.

Comment: you can avoid errors that @Gene brought up by including the line `Option Explicit` at the very top of your vba code

Comment: Try looking at [Ubound on multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644231/vba-using-ubound-on-a-multidimensional-array).

Comment: I fixed the typo and it still doesn't work, not sure why. Had been editing it a dozen times trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`Option Explicit` is exactly what would save you the next time you are suffering from "fat fingers". Just do not forget to declare the other variables:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()    
    MsgBox Pricer(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100))    
End Sub

Function Pricer(arrP As Variant) As Double

    Dim sd, avg, PriceUB, PriceLB
    sd = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDevP(arrP)
    avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(arrP)
    PriceUB = avg + sd
    PriceLB = avg - sd
    MsgBox UBound(arrP)
    Pricer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(arrP)

End Function
```

To use the formula in Excel worksheet, pass it like this:

[image]

The semicolon could be a comma, depending on your language settings:

[image]

---

To make the `Pricer()` work with `Range()` as an Excel formula this is what to do:

```
Function Pricer(arrP As Range) As Double

    MsgBox arrP.Cells.Count
    Pricer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(arrP)

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry yes that was a typo - still doesnt not work after correcting it though.

Comment: @user5670600 - what happens if you run the `TestMe()`.

Comment: It returns correctly, but perhaps the difference comes from passing Tester a constructed array vs using the =Pricer() function on a range inside of my spreadsheet.

Comment: @user5670600 - yes, it does not work, because the parameter is of type `Variant` and not of type `Range`. Change the `arrP As Range` in the parameter and it would work.

Comment: @user5670600 - instead of `UBound` write `arrP.Cells.Count`.