# Loop Array from UBound to LBound and check values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an array, loop from `UBound` to `LBound` and check values with the below code.

I 'm receiving an error on line:

```
 If arrPart(i) = strResult Then
```

> Run time error 9

The range I try to import in array:

[image]

**Code:**

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub ArrayTest()

        Dim LastColumn As Long, CounterPart As Long, i As Long
        Dim arrPart As Variant
        Dim strResult As String

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            strResult = "N"

            'Set as an array the 4 last matches
            arrPart = .Range(Cells(1, LastColumn - 3), Cells(1, LastColumn))

            CounterPart = 0

            For i = UBound(arrPart) To LBound(arrPart) Step -1

                If arrPart(i) = strResult Then
                    CounterPart = CounterPart + 1
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next

        End With

    End Sub
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `arrPart` is a 2 dimensional array that has to be used like `arrPart(row, column)`. You can use `UBound(arrPart, 1)` for `row` and `UBound(arrPart, 2)` for `column`.

Comment: `If arrPart(1,i) = strResult Then`  Also make sure you append the parent to the `Cells()` inside the `Range()` or you will get an error if that worksheet is not the active one: `arrPart = .Range(.Cells(1, LastColumn - 3), .Cells(1, LastColumn))`

Comment: You can also double transpose your array to get a single dimension array `WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(1, LastColumn - 3), .Cells(1, LastColumn))))`

Comment: You might want to check the following post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644231/vba-using-ubound-on-a-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per all the comments above:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayTest()

    Dim LastColumn As Long, CounterPart As Long, i As Long
    Dim arrPart As Variant
    Dim strResult As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        strResult = "N"

        'Set as an array the 4 last matches
        arrPart = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastColumn))

        CounterPart = 0

        For i = UBound(arrPart, 2) To LBound(arrPart, 2) Step -1

            If arrPart(1, i) = strResult Then
                CounterPart = CounterPart + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

    End With

    Debug.Print CounterPart
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table of cells starting from `B4`.

[image: scren]

This is how you find out the size of the table, transfer the values into an array and iterate through them.

```
Public Sub ArrayTest()

    Dim r_start As Range
    Set r_start = Range("B4")

    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = Range(r_start, r_start.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

    Dim arrPart() As Variant
    arrPart = r_start.Resize(1, n).Value

    Dim strResult As String
    strResult = "N"

    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 0

    For i = 1 To n
        If arrPart(1, i) = strResult Then
            counter = counter + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print counter

End Sub
```