# Why is function returning zero?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two functions to read csv data files and import to 2D arrays. Using a simple macro to call these function I always get the correct array size for the files imported but the return value of the `ImportCSV2Array()` function is inconsistent. I have included diagnostic statements to the immediate window which show that the function variable assigned as the return vaule (i.e. the dimension of the array) is correct both in the calling and called functions. However, when I import some files I get Return 0 and I cannot understand why? Please can anyone suggest what I'm missing?

Here is the calling function

```
Public Function ImportDataLog() As Boolean

Dim headerArr() As Variant
Dim filePath As String
Dim csvret As Long

On Error Resume Next
' Open file dialog to get a test file name, including path.
filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                "Test Data Files (*.csv), *.csv", 1, _
                "Select Pressure Test File")
'Debug.Print "Selected file " & filePath

' Allocate basic array before using.
ReDim headerArr(1, 1)
csvret = 0
' Read csv file and fill array with data
Application.StatusBar = "Importing . . ."
csvret = ImportCSV2Array(filePath, headerArr)

' Here csvret and UBound(headerArr, 1) should match.
Debug.Print "Return " & csvret; " (UB) " & UBound(headerArr, 1) '!!

If csvret = 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Error Importing Test Data!"
    ImportDataLog = False
    'Exit Function
End If

Debug.Print "LastRecord "; headerArr(UBound(headerArr, 1), UBound(headerArr, 2))
ImportDataLog = True
Application.StatusBar = False

End Function
```

The csv files are typically either a 2-row 'Test Header' file or a 'Test Results' file with thousands of records in a table format. When I import a 'Header' file output is:-

```
Allocated Array 1 Rows X 37 Columns
Return 1 (UB) 1
LastRecord 50.000
True
```

Return and (UB) values match as expected.
But the output for a 'Results' file is:-

```
Allocated Array 8498 Rows X 9 Columns
Return 0 (UB) 8498
LastRecord 5
True
```

Here I do not understand why I get 'Return 0 (UB) 8498`?

The import function I am calling is this:-

```
' Function for importing data from csv files to 2D array.
Public Function ImportCSV2Array(csvFileName As String, ByRef arr() As Variant) As Long

Dim row_number As Long
Dim col_Offset As Integer
Dim LineFromFile As String
Dim LineItems() As String
Dim LineNum As Long
Dim Field As Variant
Dim FileNumber As Integer

FileNumber = FreeFile
Close #FileNumber
row_number = 0
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' First pass to gauge the array dimensions required
Open csvFileName For Input As #FileNumber
Do Until EOF(FileNumber)
    Line Input #FileNumber, LineFromFile
    row_number = row_number + 1
Loop ' Until EOF(FileNumber)

If InStr(1, LineFromFile, "END") >= 1 Then
    row_number = row_number - 1
End If
LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
' ReDim tha array to fit the incoming data
ReDim arr(0 To row_number - 1, 0 To UBound(LineItems))
row_number = 0
' Diagnostic to check array sized OK
Debug.Print "Allocated Array " & UBound(arr, 1) & " Rows X " & UBound(arr, 2); " Columns"
Close #FileNumber

' Now import the data to the array line by line.
Open csvFileName For Input As #FileNumber
Do Until EOF(FileNumber)
    Line Input #FileNumber, LineFromFile
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")

    For Each Field In LineItems
        If Field <> "" Then
            arr(row_number, col_Offset) = LineItems(col_Offset)
            col_Offset = col_Offset + 1
        End If
    Next Field
    row_number = row_number + 1
    col_Offset = 0
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
Loop ' Until EOF(FileNumber)
Close #FileNumber

' Set return value to show array's first dimension
ImportCSV2Array = UBound(arr, 1)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Function
```

The two functions appear to work fine, i.e. import the data OK, but I feel that if the return value is not as expected I'm missing an error that might be important later on when I process the arrays. Any advice please?

**Solution**
With error trapping off the problem is with some files the `row_number` is incrementing beyond `UBound(arr, 1)`. So with a bit of error checking this solution works:-

```
Do Until EOF(FileNumber)
    Line Input #FileNumber, LineFromFile
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
    If row_number > UBound(arr, 1) Or InStr(1, LineFromFile, "END") >= 1 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    For Each Field In LineItems
        If Field <> "" Then
            arr(row_number, col_Offset) = LineItems(col_Offset)
            col_Offset = col_Offset + 1
        End If
    Next Field
    row_number = row_number + 1
    col_Offset = 0
Loop ' UnLineNumtil EOF(FileNumber)
```

Giving the expected result:

```
Return 8498 (UB) 8498
LastRecord 5
True
```

Comment: You are missing the error, because you have `On Error Resume Next`. Delete this line and never use it in the next few months. Then, you would see where the error is coming from.

Comment: Thank you @Vityata, now I see, 'Subscript out of range'.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here, because of the `2`:

```
Debug.Print "LastRecord "; headerArr(UBound(headerArr, 1), UBound(headerArr, 2))
```

as this is the only place the array is redim-ed, and it does not have `2` in its second dimension:

```
ReDim headerArr(1, 1)
```

[VBA using ubound on a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644231/vba-using-ubound-on-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: The problem is that the `row_number` is incrementing beyond the `UBound(arr,1)` set in the Redim  in `ImportCSV2Array`, so I need to capture that. `HeaderArr` gets resized by the ReDim statement in `ImportCSV2Array`. If I comment out the `ReDim headerArr(1, 1)` statement it makes no difference; I had put that line of code in just to provide an initial allocation, but it's not required.  Thanks anyway.